# Looking for a font where the capital A has a round top

Tags: fonts, typography, characters

I am looking for a font

- (should be available as math mode serif font)
- (uppercase *A* from this font should not look out of place next to the remaining letters from computer modern math)
- has an uppercase letter *A* that does not have a typical triangular top, but is more rounded instead. Imagine combining features of the top half of *O* with the bottom half of *H*. Kind of like this (but not as ugly):

[image: Uppercase A that has the bottom of a H and the top of a O]

I have no idea whether such a glyph actually exists. Also I don't know whether it could actually look good in practice. All I know is that it looks good in my mind (although I imagine it's features somewhat different from what is displayed in my mockup picture, with the two vertical strokes being neither exactly parallel nor of the same thickness).

Comment: To close-voters: please read first the beautiful answer.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: ...look at the not-so-nice, external link-only other answer that has nothing to do with (La)TeX.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Which shows the question is off-topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 ways: make your own, or find a font.

1. Make your own

Here is a sample with an inverted U and a rule, which supports the smaller math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel,graphicx}
\savestack\UAtextstyle{\stackon[-2.7pt]{$\rule[2.3pt]{4pt}{.35pt}$}{\scalebox{-1}{$U$}}}
\def\UA{\scalerel*{\UAtextstyle}{X}}
\begin{document}
$Ax + \UA x$

$\scriptstyle Ax + \UA x$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one finds the letter too wide, one can try to squeeze it a slight bit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel,graphicx}
\savestack\UAtextstyle{\scalebox{.9}[1]{\stackon[-2.7pt]{$\rule[2.3pt]{4pt}{.35pt}$}{\scalebox{-1}{$U$}}}}
\def\UA{\scalerel*{\UAtextstyle}{X}}
\begin{document}
$Ax + \UA x$

$\scriptstyle Ax + \UA x$
\end{document}
```

[image]

2. Find a font

None of what follows fits the bill for math support or even being compatible with CM fonts.  But it may give an idea of what is out there.

The font Bretagne Gaelic for starters.

[image]

Others... Bridgnorth seems to be almost identical to a font called Lautenbach

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sans Serif fonts may be a better alternative...

[image]

[image]

[image]

I doubt that drop caps is what you are looking for, but just in case...

[image]

It is nearly identical to similar drop-caps fonts namced Gloucester Initialen as well as Gotische Initialen.

For something also drop-caps,

[image]

For something that is doesn't seem to fit other categories, there is Herkules

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following link has a nice round top font (there are actually thirty to choose from):

- http://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Brie.htm

Comment: Can you maybe point at a serif font that features a round-top "`A`"? I'm asking because the OP appears to have indicated a preference for serif fonts.