# Good fonts for text starting with Victorian Initials

Tags: fonts

This question is induced by a beautiful answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328429/26134.
I know, that it is opinion based, but I am interested in at least  opinion of 
Steven B. Segletes, the author of this answer.

And the question is: which fonts may be suggested as text fonts for a material starting with Victorian Initials?

Comment: I'll give it some more thought, though my initial impression has been that drop-caps stand on their own so well (different size, even color), that there are fewer "compatibility" issues with the adjacent primary font as compared with, for example, the thrust of your referenced question, in which the sought-after letter must be the same size/color as the primary font, kern with it compatibly, comparable stroke widths, angles, etc.

Comment: EB Garamond comes with nice initials where the decorations and the letter are separate.  This allows to color them differently, see http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/putting-colors-in-initials/

Comment: I don't know what you are looking for, really. Are you talking about fonts for the initials or fonts to complement them? If so, to complement which in particular? A minimum working example is really required for the second. For the first, it would also be very useful or necessary if you know the fonts you want to use the initials with. If you are just looking for initials see, for example my answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250474/how-to-use-fancy-dropcaps-with-pdflatex/250479#250479.

Comment: @cfr I am looking for some old-fashioned fonts, which will fit to absolutely beautiful Victorian Initials.

Comment: So which initials? I don't know what you mean by 'absolutely beautiful Victorian Initials'. If you specify which ones you mean, somebody might have an idea.

Comment: @cfr The Victorian Initials from the linked answer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/i1J1j.jpg

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to get the initials, then. And a link to the font if it is not in TeX Live. That's just an image. How are you producing them?

Comment: @cfr All is taken from this answer  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328429/26134, as it was written in my question. Hence I do not know the initials. I saw them first time in my life and I am enchanted.

Comment: OK. I give up. I don't see the point of asking for fonts to complement initials you don't know how to produce. If you are looking for the initials themselves, why not ask the answer's author where the font can be found? Or at least say that's what you want. But finding fonts is not really on topic here.

Comment: OK. I guess the initials are these: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lHPIM.png ?

Answer (score 1):

[image: VictorianInitials1]

The font is available in truetype format. Detailed information:

```
Family:              Victorian Initials One
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           Victorian Initials One
PostScript name:     VictorianInitials-One
Version:             Version 1.0; 2001; initial release
Unique ID:           TypographerMediengestaltung: Victorian Initials One: 2001
Designer:            Dieter Steffmann
Designer URL:        http://www.steffmann.de
Vendor URL:          http://www.steffmann.de
Copyright:           Copyright (c) Typographer Mediengestaltung, 2001. All rights reserved. Digitized by Dieter Steffmann, Kreuztal.
Vendor ID:           DST
```

I produced the image above using pdfTeX, but XeTeX or LuaTeX would obviously be much easier. The font cannot be redistributed, obviously, but is freely available (or was freely available a few years ago).

Comment: So where do I find the font, and how do I install it?

Comment: @Turion try the URL in my answer?

Comment: yes, but then I still don't know how to install or use it.

Comment: @Turion Install it however you usually install fonts for your system. Then use `fontspec` with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to access it.

Comment: @Turion Note that http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/otherfonts.html#initials are available out-of-the-box with any current TeX installation. See the package `cfr-initials` for documentation. Or use the code from the catalogue, if you prefer. Apparently, they've not heard of `cfr-initials`.

Comment: I'm (unfortunately?) using LaTeX. I can't recall ever having installed fonts on my system and then being able to use them. How would I do that with Victorian Initials? Is there a package for those as well?

Comment: @Turion You don't need a package if you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. You just install them however you install fonts for your system normally. This is system-dependent, so I can't say how you should do it. On a Mac, you'd probably use FontBook. On Linux, you'd probably put them in `~/.fonts` or `/usr/local/share/fonts` or something like that, though it depends on the distro. Then you just use `fontspec` and set the font.